# How to install WiFi and graphics driver in Debian 9?

Tags: linux, debian, drivers

I recently installed Debian 9.

Now I need to install WiFi card driver. But, I couldn't find a working one on my system.

These are my devices listed by command `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev  e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
 04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

My `/etc/apt/sourlist.list` contents:

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.0.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST     20170617-13:06]/ stretch main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ etch/updates main contrib
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ etch main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
```

**Question:** How do I install graphics and WiFi card driver?

Comment: Please look at this question : https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/680673

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson Thanks for the link, Can you tell me which device is my wireless device?

Comment: please add the output of `lsusb` to your question

Comment: Why does your sources list include ETCH???

Comment: You need to remove the lines with just etch in your sources.list

Answer (score 5):

To enable support for WiFi devices based on Broadcom wireless LAN chips, using the vendor driver on Debian systems:

Broadcom BCM4311, BCM4312, BCM4313, BCM4321, BCM4322, BCM43224, BCM43225, BCM43227, BCM43228, BCM43142, BCM4331, BCM4352, BCM4360 devices (wl)

**Installation**

1- Add a "non-free" component to `/etc/apt/sources.list` for your Debian version, for example:

```
# Stretch
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

2- Update the list of available packages. Install the relevant/latest linux-image, linux-headers and broadcom-sta-dkms packages:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

3- Unload conflicting modules:

```
# modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

4- Load the wl module:

```
# modprobe wl
```

5- Configure your wireless interface as appropriate

Comment: The sources list is mixed etch and stretch

Answer (score 2):

```
# apt install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

usually resolves such issues

Comment: It says: `E: Unable to locate package firmware-linux-nonfree`

Comment: add "contrib" and "non-free" to these lines:  
`deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free`  
then `apt update` to update your list of packages.  
See https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList for details

Answer (score 0):

I installed my old HP laptop wifi driver by the instructions of this link:
http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43/

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer